# Unable to fetch only values from a List in Groovy with Jmeter script

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

In groovy, I am getting below output in List. I am using Jmeter JSR223 Post processor for the script. My List print below data in result.

```
def a = [{Zip=36448, CountryID=2}]
```

I want to fetch only values (36448 and 2) from this List and not Key. How Can I do that?

Comment: You want to fetch those values as what data structure? Is list `a` known to always be a singleton?

Comment: Values should be string. This is coming from Database query result. Zip is column name and 36448 is value.

Comment: You mean `def (zip, countryId) = [a[0].Zip, a[0].CountryID]`? Or you can declare them separately: `def zip = a[0].Zip` and `def countryId = a[0].CountryID`

Answer (score 2):

For simple single instance fetch do this:

```
def zip = a.first().Zip
def countryId = a.first().CountryID
```

Seems pretty straight forward if those are only known values that you want.

If you want all Zips and CountryIDs then you can do this:

```
def zips = a*.Zip
def countryIds = a*.CountryID
```

That will return 2 Lists one with all the Zips, and one with all the CountryIDs using the spread operator.

Comment: It is throwing error "javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.first() is applicable for argument types: () values: []". When I ran code a.getAt(2) then it returns "Z". a.getAt(3) retursn "i" in the Output

Comment: @Arun The `first()` method is defined on Collection.  The error message says that whatever you are calling `first()` on is a String not a Collection so that's why it's not working.  In your example code variable `a` was Collection so it would work in that situation.

Comment: Ok . I converted it to Collection and it worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the data structure is inside your list your code is not a valid Groovy code.

For [Map](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-maps) it would be something like:

```
a[0].collect {it -> it.value}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)